# IEEEtran table formatting doesn't work

Tags: tables, formatting, ieeetran

I'm totally new to this so any insight would be greatly appreciated. I want to create a document using IEEEtran and despite trying on multiple operating systems and editors I can't seem to get tables to format correctly. For the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}

\maketitle

\IEEEPARstart{S}{ome} text

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]
I know the table title should contain Roman numerals and the caption should be in small caps. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The `conference` class option provides something similar to what you want. If you want to stick to the `journal` option, why do you want to change it if this is for a journal submission?

Comment: Delete `compsoc` option

Comment: Thank you all, removing compsoc did the trick. The thing is every journal submission I've read so far had small caps table captions, that's why I thought I was getting the wrong table format somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not use `compsoc` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}

\maketitle

\IEEEPARstart{S}{ome} text

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```